# Distorted action icon and no label for standard and custom action in Sandbox

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

We are facing an issue with SF1 in our QA Sandbox,
When accessing any record, we are getting distorted action icons at the bottom without the action labels for both standard and custom actions. This behavior is seen in both Android and IOS app.

[image: Issue seen in QA Sandbox]

Although for an IOS app we are able to get rid of the issue by clearing the app cache by going to Setting->Advanced->clear cache in SF1(for IOS). But when logging in with another user, the same issue is seen and need to clear cache again.
This issue is not seen when logging in Dev Sandbox in the same SF1 app for both Android and IOS.

[image: As Expected in Dev Sandbox]

Environment Details:

IOS device: Iphone 6S Version: 10.1.1(14B100)   |   SF1 App version: 12.3

Android device: MI4i Version: 5.0.2 LRX22G  |   SF1 App version: 12.1

Comment: If this is OOTB. Maybe contact SF support?

Answer (score 0):

After logging a case with Salesforce Support with the help of the support team, we were able to identify the root cause of this issue.

The root cause of this issue was a VF page that was the including an outdated version of the  SLDS library from the static resource in your org.
The above scenario would also result in other CSS related UI issues.

To avoid this one should either use  or the latest version of SLDS in the static resource(not recommended) for VF pages.
More Info. at: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/visualforce/

Thanks!